# PHP redirect is only working on every every other page

Tags: php

I'm trying to make two pages, where you have to go to the first page to have access to the second page. I'm doing this in WordPress and trying to add PHP code snippets to make this work. I have it working but only every other time.

I set the variable :

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION[ 'display_page2' ] = TRUE;
?>
```

Page2:

```
<?php

session_start();

if ((isset($_SESSION['display_page2']) && $_SESSION['display_page2'] === true) || isset($_POST['nf-field-184'])) {
    //run page two
} else {
    header('Location:http://www.lytrod.com/intellicutinstallation-2/');
}
// clears the variable
unset($_SESSION['display_page2']);
```

Comment: Your `unset()` only triggers when you successfully load page 2.

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: Im really out of my element. I dont really know PHP very well at all. if I dont clear the variable im not able to proceed to the next page. How can adjust my code to make this work. thank you for reaching out

Comment: else {
like this? dosen't seem to work 
 header('Location:http://www.lytrod.com/intellicutinstallation-2/');
exit();
}

Comment: exit( header('Location:http://www.lytrod.com/intellicutinstallation-2/')); I did this but it didnt seem to work

Comment: Obsidian Age your exactly right please let me know if you have any solutions

Comment: hi @AlexLytle, have you check the php error log?

Comment: yeah, its the weirdest thing ever. i check my developer tools and it says no errors. half the time when you go to this link it will redirect you https://www.lytrod.com/intellicut-install-demo/.

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
    header('Location:http://www.lytrod.com/intellicutinstallation-2/');
    exit();
}
```